# How do I create an interactive Sheet Manager?

Tags: excel, vba

This is a tricky one for me, and I am desperately looking for help.

I don't have much experience with coding or VBA everything I've done below was from googling and trying different things before it worked. Hence, the code is a total mess and it only does a fraction of what I need it to do..

To explain things, I have a main sheet that needs to display and be used to create/delete sheets.
I have a sheet where I have prices for glass, aluminium and other materials, and different Template sheets for Windows/Doors/Roofs, that all pull the prices from Reference sheet.

What I did below is try to create a code so that when I type the number of windows I need in the main sheet, I'll get that many copies of the Window template sheet. Then I have a few formula that sums all sheets up and gives me a total price. This way, I can go back to each sheet and edit the window configuration.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Excel.Range)
    If target.Cells.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(target) And target.Address = "$B$4" Then
        Select Case target.Value
            Case 1 To 15: copierW
            Case Is > 15: copierW
            End Select
            End If
End Sub


Sub copierW()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, x As Integer
Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = Sheets("W")
x = ActiveSheet.Range("b4")

For numtimes = 1 To x
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("W").Copy _
    After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Next
Worksheets(1).Select
End Sub
```

Now the issue I have, is, let's say, I initially type in "8" as number of windows needed, it will create 8 copies. But if I change my mind and want only 6, and type in 6, it will create an additional 6 copies.

I'm looking for a way for the code to understand it needs to keep the 1-6 sheets with all the information already in it, but delete the excess only. I wanted to try deleting all Sheets names Window (6+) based on the name, but it would still execute the copy function first.

I am so confused as to where to even start or how to search for what I need.

There's other things that I need to do, like the main sheet displaying a certain cell from each sheet, but stack them under each-other. So A2 in Window1(sheet) would be displayed in Main sheet - C4, but A2 in Window2(sheet) would be displayed in Main Sheet - C5, etc.

Please let me know if you need more information or anything else I can do.

Comment: What if you want to have 8 copies and then 6 copies later - how do you distinguish these two scenarios?

Comment: You could have a separate procedure for deleting sheets.

Comment: Well, I'd simply change "windows needed" number to 14 instead of just using the sheet to create a one-off. So I'm thinking of some sort of count function that can count how many sheets share the same name and only copy what else is needed. 

We have a lot of revisions, sometimes up to 6-7 revisions, and I don't want to lose what I've done before. I'm not sure how to do that yet.

Comment: I don't really understand how this system works, but as I see it the only way is to have a process for deleting unwanted sheets. So you specify the number and name and loop backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your comment.
This will Just name them "W" and the number.
In your case it didn´t work bc you didn´t change the counter function. This resulted in not counting and therefore it started to add them another time wich is why the error occured.

```
Sub copierW()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, x As Integer
Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = Sheets("W")
x = ActiveSheet.Range("b4")
Count = 0
For Each sh In Worksheets
    If Left(sh.Name, 1) = "W" and Right(sh.Name,1)="." Then
        Count = Count + 1
    End If
Next sh
needed_copies = x - Count
For numtimes = 1 To needed_copies
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("W").Copy _
    After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Count2 = Count + numtimes
    ActiveSheet.Name = "W" & Count2 & "."
Next
Worksheets(1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: That is perfect, thank you so much!
I know it might be asking too much as this point, but how would I go and count backwards to delete all sheets that have a higher number than the one entered in "B4"?
Again, thank you so much, it's so hard for me to understand this stuff and this has been a life-saver!

Comment: You can do another question for that or you change the question because otherwise this would be misleading.

Comment: I've made another post, I tried tagging your name in but not sure it worked.